# Destructuring string in generic argument using template literal types

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function `get` which takes an `object` and a `string` path as an argument and resolves that path into the object, returning the targeted value. Ideally, I want TypeScript to be able to guess the type of the result.

So, for example, this works :

```js
declare function get<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, path: K): T[K]
declare function get(entity: object, path: string): any

const value = get({ foo: { bar: 45 }, baz: true }, "baz") // type boolean
```

Now things get interesting for nested objects. This works :

```js
declare function get<T extends object, K extends T extends Record<infer A, infer B> ? `${A & string}.${(keyof B) & string}` : never>
    (entity: T, path: K): T extends Record<infer A, infer B> ? T[A][keyof B] : never
    
declare function get<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, path: K): T[K]
declare function get(entity: object, path: string): any

const value = get({ foo: { bar: 45 } }, "foo.bar") // type number
```

However, if I add a property to the input object, it stops working :

```js
const value = get({ foo: { bar: 45 }, baz: true }, "foo.bar") // type any
```

**[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMAeAFXhAA8MRVgBneHAIwCtwMAaeAaUpp1G8CtVr0mAJXA4YwEllSIQMeAEEei5aoBCAPngB%20eAAMAJAG818AGTwGGGIoIBfAHSWAFAGsQATxxEeB0ASlt7R2cXE3gALnhUEAA3FT0AKHhM%20E86bAw-eLIeAAcoDAALeN4QwoFxYWkwWXktFXVNJTb9IxEAbTUAXV7fAKCdAbiE5JUMrLTQSFgEFHRsPEJicjqhJlYOTB5%20MR34EcCRPRzUPIKRErLKvhq%203gH58Gg4JDRMXHwiDBXG7xPace4VeIOJyoAjPKCoPxpNJNVAOeBJKAQZAIAC8G0BFiQOBw8UJLFg8QALABWeAuHjkgBe8Uc2LpPAARIhiW5yTAOSEgA)**

Is there a solution to this ? Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj5llW) recursive type work for you?  If so I can write up an answer (tomorrow, probably, it's late here).

Comment: @jcalz Yes it seems to work. Why not use `never` instead of `Invalid`?

Comment: @jcalz This simpler solution based on yours is perfect for my needs (when the path is not recognized, `get` should return `any`, not fail) :

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgJIDsAmEAeAeAKgGigAUpNgI0BnKC4AJwEtkBzAPigF4iSMzKoADACQBvRgDMItKAGkAvgDoR4yVABKs-lAD8AKCj6Z3XqioBrCCAD2YqDm2x4SNJlwBtaQF0CqtgC4oyBAAbiq+egbEpOQmUOZWNnZatq6EHlD+gSG0ANw6OugAxgA2AIa00GIArsgFwPSWyFBMEMC4BJE80VQ0DMwsABTkdaD++FBgJcAAFv5wCCjo2GOEbFF8mSpJG1L+hACUs44LLsss+RDFZRXVtfWNza04A0P0I7YEE9P+PYxMB1AlZAgKB5AoNGhQSwAIwAVhwoMIoGJLJZ-IioWV-AAWACsUFkBAxAC9-HRKtBZLkdGDkBCggBGeEPfrQmEEABEyMs7L22RBNLpACYmS0WbCORjaDzcgLgFAggBmEXAMVsqCclHySXS6nguVBLHK1UcrnyHWy+V4zjM1kSkpE6X8vXygBsRtt6tNkvkwEsADF6BgIKgeSCgA

Comment: Anyway, very smart solution. Thank you. You can post it and I'll accept it.

Comment: I’ll definitely do so and explain how it works (and yeah, `never` is sufficient I think. But I’m on mobile right now so I can’t do it until later today probably.  If someone else comes along and answers first that’s fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to represent what you're trying to do as a single, [recursive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) `DeepIndex<T, P>` type operation that takes a type `T` and a dotted path string `P` and returns the type you get when you index a value of type `T` with the path represented by `P`.  The first implementation here is restrictive: it will check that `P` is a valid path (and additionally doesn't point to a property of type `never`) and issue a warning on `get()` if it isn't:

```
type DeepIndex<T, P extends string> = P extends `${infer K}.${infer R}` ?
    K extends keyof T ? DeepIndex<T[K], R> : never :
    P extends keyof T ? T[P] : never;
type AllowedPath<T, P extends string> =
    P extends any ? DeepIndex<T, P> extends never ? never : P : never;
declare function get<T extends object, P extends string>(
    entity: T, path: AllowedPath<T, P>): DeepIndex<T, P>;
```

`DeepIndex<T, P>` works by checking to see if the path `P` contains a dot.

If `P` does contain a dot, then [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) inference splits `P` to get the key `K` before the first dot, and the rest `R` after the first dot.  If `K` is a key of `T`, then it recurses down.  Otherwise, this is a bad path and it resolves to `never`.

If `P` does not contain a dot, then it is the supposed to be the final key of the path and we can just index into `T` with `P`.  If that doesn't work because `P` is not a key of `T`, then this is a bad path and it resolves to `never`.

`AllowedPath<T, P>` takes a type `T` and a candidate path string `P`, and extracts from `P` only those paths which resolve to a non-`never` type via `DeepIndex<T, P>`.  So if `P` is a valid path, `AllowedPath<T, P>` is just `P`.  But if `P` is not a valid path, `AllowedPath<T, P>` is `never`.  Note that if `P` is a union of valid and invalid paths, the output will be just the valid ones.

You can verify that `get()` works the way described above:

```
const obj = { foo: { bar: 45 }, baz: true };
get(obj, "foo.bar").toFixed(2); // okay
get(obj, "foo").bar.toFixed(2); // okay
get(obj, "bar"); // error!
get(obj, "foo."); // error!
get(obj, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "..." : "baz"); // error!
get(obj, "foo.bar.toFixed") // this is okay, not sure if you want that, but ‍♂️
```

For the `obj` object, `"foo"` and `"foo.bar"` are both accepted and result in the appropriate output types.  For invalid paths like plain `"bar"` or `"foo."` (with an ending dot), the compiler errors saying that those paths are not assignable to `never` (which I'll admit isn't the most user-friendly error. It can be improved somewhat but this might be out of scope here).  Also notice that the case where the path is a union of invalid and valid paths like `"..."` (bad) and `"baz"` (good), the compiler error complains about the bad part and says that it's not assignable to `"baz"`.

Finally, note that `DeepIndex` allows you to "walk off the end" of the declared type, since even primitive types like `number` have methods and therefore `"foo.bar.toFixed"` resolves to a function-typed property.  (If this is a problem, it can also be improved, by forcing `DeepIndex` to check whether `T` is an object before proceeding.  But again, possibly out of scope.)

---

In your comments you indicate that you'd like all paths to be accepted and just have the output type be `any` if the path is invalid.  This permissive version is easier to implement, by getting rid of `AllowedPath` entirely (since we never want to reject anything) and changing `DeepIndex`'s implementation so it resolves to `any` instead of `never` in the case of a bad path:

```
type DeepIndex<T, P extends string> = P extends `${infer K}.${infer R}` ?
    K extends keyof T ? DeepIndex<T[K], R> : any :
    P extends keyof T ? T[P] : any;
declare function get<T extends object, P extends string>(
    entity: T, path: P): DeepIndex<T, P>

const obj = { foo: { bar: 45 }, baz: true };
get(obj, "foo.bar").toFixed(2); // okay
get(obj, "foo").bar.toFixed(2); // okay
get(obj, "bar"); // any
get(obj, "foo."); // any
get(obj, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "..." : "baz"); // any
```

All the "okay" cases from before act the same, but the ones which formerly resulted in errors now yield `any`. You should be careful with this: [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) won't catch these (the `any` here is explicit), so someone who uses this might end up doing unsafe things without realizing it:

```
get(obj, "foo.bаr").toFixed(2); // okay
```

Do you see the problem?  Probably not, but the "a" in that path is actually ["а", a Cyrillic letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(Cyrillic)) and so `"foo.bаr"` is an invalid path.  The compiler does not complain, but returns `any`, which lets you index into it with `toFixed` or `toBroken` or whatever, and you'll only find out about the issue at runtime.

This might not be likely (especially accidental-or-malicious character set changes), but I just want to point out that falling-back-to-`any` instead of issuing a warning has risks.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlaAXATgS3u7AbsgN4BQpSlS6AnjMgCIQQwCSwAJhAB4A8AKgBokABSQ90ETlCRQs2YAHMAfEgC8o8d0nSkAAwAkxBQDMImJAGkAvgDojp86mt6kAfgpUvlrTo4yAawgaAHsTJH53JCYWdi4+fgBtSwBdYRRVAC4kYAgiC0zPL0oxCSl-JCDQ8Mi3CMSRFKRs3PyAbiLqOmQAQQAbPpCAdwgOERB0AAsBYVLtcpk5HCVVNU6vOb8ZEGAaKJi2Th4Z0VUy3VanOsuCzRa88w6vLng+kExkEwBXYDxsEOASEUEHQAl8CyQIQARgArCB4Wbg3RLBQqAAU6yoUnwtGyQiQcCm2X6gxGYwm03xImUAEpsgc4scqcoOp14AC5JDYeokMQkCYQiFsnyoe9sgAWACsSGswlFAC9slgvshrE8qMD0GjoTDhAAiAUhWyizB6mm2dAhABi2G4ozRACYaW0kAB6V2QgIgGidTXa2H6w1m43vC3W232p0u92e72+kH+3VIPUms3Rj3mTAhTAAQnjWp1gcFtjTbozmCzufzieEAFkKbZMDsOCEwGiaUheEgAAy2aV1PW2Id65rJhWlmOZ7N5rx+wvJw0hzBhm12jhmsvUSbYGQ72M0YTAELoWRfD5IbDhUJfJBDHYnqYTOVfE+APg3AOy7gFgCQBCZIB4P-Is4JvOBrFlCgAMIKa5qWqukbOpuU65kgADCNA4AMuDJmBerCIKMBQKQ1jkKAkCwAgyAiOYYA7lAhAkABVC0PQ0TMIc8QnJsEIoisPIcbohjGMAZgWDY9gCUJziuB4xRUD45wVFUYQRPsLGMgkyRpKgWRIDseyFNJJRIvJwSKbU9SNKOOnqpQLxvOe3y-PgAJAiCYJyTIOrwugiJubI8grBi+niMAOI0HiwiEpM2QiHSzGxEcCSzMo9GUOywCcjqPJ8oawpICaErSrKuUgIq1CYCqMpWc5BYBguoHvMG0ERhwjpwTGIRej6gHVUmIEhMGJork1LXpvu1bAamrUejpY01b1JaTdpuwzUm9ZTI2zatu2nY9n2USDsOo4psVE5TUty1Fka4GQYNa7DZu7XesInQxlCL4XieUCTCEXx9BwwAAOQnlCEDCChaF9BhepYThIR4Xm1hUOQpBAA)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I understand the risk with `any` but have no choice. In my real use case, the path can actually have a more complex syntax and I only check part of that syntax and leave the rest to `any` (because it might not be recognizable without an actual type-based string parser (does such a thing exist now that we have template literal types ?)).